# NilClass error setting up mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailer

I'm trying to set up a mailer for the first time.  I've followed the [RubyGuides Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) to the letter, or so I thought.  I keep getting a NilClass error.  Originally, it was because my email address wasn't saving to the DB (left if off of the controller).  Now I'm able to see my email address in the rails console, but still running into NilClass or an "wrong number of arguments 0 for 1" error

Here's my controller:

```
def create
@pc = Pc.new(pc_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @pc.save
    TestMailer.message(@pc).deliver_later

    format.html { redirect_to @pc, notice: 'Pc was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pc }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @pc.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My mailer:

```
   class TestMailer < ApplicationMailer
      default from: 'notifications@example.com'

      def message(pc)
        @pc = pc
        @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
        mail(to: @pc.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
      end
    end
```

I don't get what I'm missing here, any help?

Comment: you need to add the full error with backtrace, so we can see what's going on.

Comment: `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/mailers/test_mailer.rb:4:in 'message'
  app/mailers/test_mailer.rb:7:in 'message'
  app/controllers/pcs_controller.rb:31:in 'block in create'
  app/controllers/pcs_controller.rb:29:in 'create'
` is my last error

Comment: I just reproduced the nilClass error `'NoMethodError (undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass):
  app/mailers/test_mailer.rb:5:in 'message'
  app/controllers/pcs_controller.rb:31:in 'block in create'
  app/controllers/pcs_controller.rb:29:in 'create'
`

Comment: Your error doesn't match your code, you're getting the `nil` error at `app/mailers/test_mailer.rb:5` but that line is `@pc = pc` which could never fail with that error.  Show your real code.

Comment: You're right, it appears I'm only getting the `nil` error when I removed the `@pc = pc` line in an effort to figure out what's going on.  What you see there is my current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retraced my steps after a short time away from the screen.  Seems I might have failed to correctly name my email template.  Started from scratch using Ruby Guides and got it working.  New code for future lost souls:

Controller:

```
def create
@pc = Pc.new(pc_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @pc.save
    PcsMailer.email(@pc).deliver_later

    format.html { redirect_to @pc, notice: 'Pc was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pc }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @pc.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Mailer:

```
class PcsMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def email(pc)
    @pc = pc
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @pc.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

Message:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
     <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Welcome to example.com </h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Mostly copied directly from Ruby Guides, though some things were eliminated for simplicity.